# Swap 'primary' calendar id for custom user id?

Tags: java, kotlin, google-calendar-api

How should I handle users who have custom google calendar id?

(ie, not the standard id 'primary', for example they use the calendar id 'someone@gmail.com'?)

I'm following the [calendar api by google](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java), and I would like to know this information so I can swap out the default string,

`Events events = service.events().list(*this is what i want to swap out*--->"primary")`

An example of a custom calendar id, such as what I have setup for mine, [image: custom calendar id img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list the events for a calendar with a specific Id, you just need to incorporate this `calendarId` in quotes within `list()`.

**Sample:**

```
Events events = service.events().list('someone@gmail.com').execute();
```

This is important when you have more than one calendar.

To list all your calendars and their IDs, you can use the method [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list). The easiest way to retrieve all your calendars is to use the Try It API.

Comment: i have solved this, i guess having custom id's default to primary, regardless. i have tried it with multiple google accounts and different calendarid's, all default to primary. now, what i am curious about is if there are any exceptions?

Comment: There are exceptions if you have more than one calendar. You can use the following method to list all calendars you have: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list (The easiest way to retrieve all your calendars is to use the TryIt API)

Comment: i see. okay can you please put that as the answer instead? It's more of what i was looking for. thank you.